# Run X11 applications after sudo/su (local)

Tags: ubuntu, x11, sudo, root, gui

I want to sudo/su on my *local* machine and run X applications as the new user.

When I google this, all the answers seem to be ssh-oriented.

I am not ssh-ing. How do I change users and run a graphical program?

Comment: Being able to do this has security implications. To make sure this is not an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) can you tell us why you want to do this?

Comment: Please elaborate as to what program you want to run too!

Comment: Try using `gsudo` or `gksu`

Comment: @Shadur NO, these were removed long ago.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak It's been a while since I've needed to use either; what's the preferred form nowadays? `sudo -E` ?

Comment: @Shadur Since we don't know what specific app the OP wants to run as root, it's kind of impossible to answer... Best to wait till this information is added.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add permissions so that the other user can access your display.

From your user, do:

```
$ xhost +si:localuser:<otheruser>
```

(Note that the "`localuser`" keyword is a literal
part of the ACL and does not change.) 
For example,

```
$ xhost +si:localuser:edward
```

Then you can `su` into *otheruser* and run your X program(s). 
You might need to specify the server:

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0
$ yourXprogram
```

Check [xhost's manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xhost) for more details.

Comment: Why use `export` and not run `DISPLAY=:0 yourXprogram` directly?

Comment: Because the op said *"and run X applications as the new user."*, in plural. I thought that prefixing each one of those commands with `DISPLAY=:0` wasn't ideal.